# Return firstname only in a SELECT-Statement (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

For my purpose I need the Firstname of the fullname column as follows:

```
Fullname:
Doeshi, John Dr.

Goal: (Firstname)
John
```

My SELECT-Statement is defined like below:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(REPLACE(Fullname, 'Dr.', ''), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(Fullname)) - 2) AS Firstname,
    LEFT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(',', Fullname) - 1) AS Lastname,
    Fullname
FROM 
    dbo.Users
```

Currently the Select-statement returns:

```
Firstname: `i, John`

Lastname: `Doeshi`
```

Is there a better solution to get the firstname without the title only?

Sample data:

```
Firstname | Lastname | Fullname
-------------------------------
Mannum    | Anja     | Mannum, Anja
Mocheboch | Olga     | Mocheboch, Olga
n, Sascha | Sascha   | Bieten, Sascha Dr.
....
```

Comment: Can you post few sample data and results ?

Comment: There is no catch-all for this. What if you have a Junior? A hyphen in the first name? The first name has multiple parts? Or apostrophes? Or prefixes? Too many considerations. In my experience, you will get to "good enough" and probably fix the remainder manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work for `Dr.` but here is your solution fixed:

```
SELECT
RIGHT(REPLACE(Fullname, 'Dr.', ''), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(Fullname)) - 5) AS Firstname
```

And another way that my brain prefers somewhat:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(FULLNAME, 'Dr.', ''),CHARINDEX(',',FULLNAME)+2,20) AS Firstname
```

You may or may not want to wrap these in `LTRIM` `RTRIM` if there is variable spacing within the `Fullname` field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is helpful for my purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @fullname varchar(50) = 'Doeshi, John'
declare @comma int = CHARINDEX(',', @fullname)
declare @lastname varchar(50) = LEFT(@fullname, @comma - 1)
declare @rest varchar(50) = RIGHT(@fullname, LEN(@Fullname)- @comma)

declare @space int = CHARINDEX(' ', @rest)

declare @firstname varchar(50) 

if @space > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @firstname = Left(@rest, @space - 1)
    end
else
    BEGIN
        SET @firstname = @rest
    end

select @firstname, @lastname
```

It depends on the separation between surname and first names being ', ' and that there is a further space if a title follows the first name.  It works regardless of whether Title is Dr., Sir, Lady etc. and also when Title is left out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this I believe as long as your format is the same for all names. Most of this credit belongs to @GordonLinoff

```
DECLARE @fullna varchar(50) = 'Doeshi, John Dr.'

SELECT left(stuff(@fullna, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @fullna) + 1, ''), 
CHARINDEX(' ', stuff(@fullna, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @fullna) + 1, ''))) as 'First Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Supousing nomenclature is like:
LastName+','+whiteSpace+name+whiteSpace+Prefix+'.'

I think this works

```
DECLARE @v AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sub AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @v = 'Doeshi, John Dr.'
SET @sub = SUBSTRING( @v,CHARINDEX(',',@v)+2,(LEN(@v)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@v))))
PRINT SUBSTRING( @sub,0,(CHARINDEX(' ',@sub)))
```